# geary move mails to the trash, I don't want that

Tags: pantheon-mail

I  have two mail addresses, so I have two accounts at geary. But somehow geary moves automatically all my emails in my second account to the trash bin. Is there any way to stop it from doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using IMAP or POP3 to get your email? Mail clients using POP3 generally delete emails from the server after downloading them.

If you could post a screenshot of your mail settings (excluding usernames or other personal info, of course), that might help folks troubleshoot. I'd be interested to see what's different between the two accounts.

Comment: Hi Ryan, thank you for your answwer. Acutally i dont know that, cause the trouble account is yahoo mail, and geary made all the settings for yahoo automatically. the other account is a smaller mail provider and i had to made the settings by hand, and this is no POP3. In case yahoo is POP3- is there any possibility, that geary moves mails, that are not on the server anymore to the trash?

Comment: Yes - if Yahoo is set up to use POP3, Geary will delete emails from the server as it downloads them.

Comment: it delete them not only in the server - on geary itself as well. So i will try to change the settings of yahoo.